# How to compare two mp4 files in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, terminal

How to compare two mp4 files in linux?
I am using "diff 1.mp4 2.mp4" but it doesnot work.

Comment: it does for me. care to explain what exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Pavel i want to see what is the difference but it inly shows that binaries are different

Comment: the difference of two binary files is a bunch of bytes. do you want to dump them? you know that it will not be a set of "frames" or a "video" - just some binary garbage, don't you?

Comment: Are you trying to check whether two video files are different encodings of the same contents?

Answer (score 2):

In order between two binary files is just a bunch of bytes. You can use something like this in order to get the list of differing bytes:

```
cmp -l fileA fileB \
   | gawk '{printf "%08X %02X %02X\n", $1, strtonum(0$2), strtonum(0$3)}' \
   | head
```

This will give you the following result:

```
offset   byte_in_file_1 byte_in_file_2
00000051 DD             D5
00000052 9B             9C
00000053 4B             C1
00000054 8F             93
00000055 26             E6
....
```

You can't, however, easily interpret the bytes as some "images", "frames", "video sequences" or whatever if you compare MPEG files.